# Custom font in android dropdown

Tags: android, fonts, dropdown

Im working on a webapp and for some reason the custom font (font-awesome) doesn't display in an android drop-down menu. It does display on the page itself though.

Are there any workarounds or fixes for this?

```
          <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
      <label for="icon">Icoon:</label>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Icon
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu fa-font" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="noodIcon">&#xf073;</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="noodIcon">&#xf05a;</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="noodIcon">&#xf095;</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="noodIcon">&#xf249;</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="noodIcon">&#xf030;</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="noodIcon">&#xf0fa;</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Basically im using a unicode to display the icons in a dropdown menu. The only problem is, androids webview displays dropdown menus in a native containers, which does not read the custom font

Comment: show your code.

Comment: Please specify the drop down or share your code.

Comment: I did, im sorry i was in a rush

Answer (score 0):

Use **Android-Iconics** - https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics
It is a collection of icon like font-awesome,Google Material Design Icons, Octicons, Weather Icons,  Typeicons etc.

Comment: I'm trying to display unicode in a simple html dropdown. But android displays the dropdown in a native container, which does not support the unicode.